# Do neutrinos interact gravitationally?

Tags: particle-physics, gravity, experimental-physics, neutrinos

I know that, in theory at least, they do. However, I was wondering if there has been any experimental confirmation of this, or any other reasons for perhaps thinking that they do not interact via the gravitational force.

Comment: If I'm not wrong their mass is negligible right? Like many factors lesser than the mass of an electron. If it is so, how could they show an appreciable gravitational interaction?

Comment: They are, and I don't know how they could, I was wondering if there was some plausible way to test for it.

Comment: Firstly, I have negligible knowledge about neutrinos. Secondly, despite the little knowledge I have, I'm pretty sure they are very and I mean very very hard to detect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Photons interact [gravitationally,](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_lens) as seen in gravitational lensing.

> A gravitational lens is a distribution of matter (such as a cluster of galaxies) between a distant light source and an observer, that is capable of bending the light from the source as the light travels towards the observer. This effect is known as gravitational lensing, and the amount of bending is one of the predictions of Albert Einstein's general theory of relativity.

So even massless particles follow the general relativity equations

If one googles "[gravitational lensing and neutrinos](https://www.google.gr/search?q=gravitational%20lensing%20and%20neutrinos&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b&gfe_rd=cr&ei=9oD9WOfKM47EXpOckbgK) a lot of papers proposing effects  come up.

There are various future experiments  proposed, from indirect ones deciphering the [cosmic microwave bacground](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1309.5383.pdf), to the use of neutrino detectors .